# Return ID in insert oracle

Tags: oracle

I have a package with a `INSERT` in a sp, and I want to return the id of that insert. The table have a sequence and a trigger for the identity, but in the sp I don't know how can I return the id of the insert that i'm doing, because in the code java I need to use it.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY PLUSALT.INSERTAR
IS
PROCEDURE INSERTAR_ESTRATEGIA(
    P_USUARIO     IN VARCHAR2,
    P_CAMPAÑA     IN NUMBER,
    P_FKPLANTILLA IN NUMBER,
    P_NOMBRE      IN VARCHAR2)
IS
BEGIN
  INSERT
  INTO ESTRATEGIA VALUES
    (
      NULL,
      P_CAMPAÑA,
      P_USUARIO,
      P_FKPLANTILLA,
      P_NOMBRE,
      NULL,
      SYSDATE,
      1,
      'Y'
    );
END;
END;
/
```

Ths is the table

```
CREATE TABLE ESTRATEGIA
(
    ESID               NUMBER(25) NOT NULL,
    FK_CAMPAÑA         NUMBER(5) NOT NULL,
    FK_USUARIO         NUMBER(8) NOT NULL,
    FK_PLANTILLAESTRA  NUMBER(8),
    ESNOMBRE           VARCHAR2(100),
    ESDESCRIPCION      VARCHAR2(300),
    ESFCHCREACION      DATE,
    FKESTADO           NUMBER(3) NOT NULL,
    ESACTIVA           CHAR(1)
)
;
```

The sequence

```
CREATE SEQUENCE ESTRATEGIA_SEC
START WITH 1 
INCREMENT BY 1 
NOMAXVALUE;
```

The trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER TRIG_ESTRATEGIA
  BEFORE INSERT ON ESTRATEGIA
  FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN
    SELECT ESTRATEGIA_SEC.nextval INTO :new.ESID FROM dual;
  END
;
```

Comment: Where is the ID?

Comment: @KaushikNayak the ID is the first element, because I have a trigger with sequence for that value.

Comment: First element of what?

Comment: @KaushikNayak I put the table, sequence and the trigger in the question.

Comment: Thanks. Let me take a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

USE `RETURNING INTO` in the insert with an OUT parameter. Use this parameter  `P_ESID` in your java code.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY PLUSALT.INSERTAR
IS
PROCEDURE INSERTAR_ESTRATEGIA(
    P_USUARIO     IN VARCHAR2,
    P_CAMPAÑA     IN NUMBER,
    P_FKPLANTILLA IN NUMBER,
    P_NOMBRE      IN VARCHAR2,
    P_ESID        OUT NUMBER)
IS
BEGIN
  INSERT
  INTO ESTRATEGIA VALUES
    (
      NULL,
      P_CAMPAÑA,
      P_USUARIO,
      P_FKPLANTILLA,
      P_NOMBRE,
      NULL,
      SYSDATE,
      1,
      'Y'
    ) RETURNING ESID INTO P_ESID ;
END;
END;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/returninginto_clause.htm

Quick demonstration.

```
SQL> create table t (id int);

Table created.

SQL> create sequence s;

Sequence created.

SQL> var x number
SQL> insert into t values(s.nextval) returning id into :x;

1 row created.

SQL> print x

         X
----------
         1
```